# Using Awk and match()

Tags: bash, awk

I have a sequencing file to analyze that has many lines like the following tab separated line:

```
chr12   3356475 .   C   A   76.508  .   AB=0;ABP=0;AC=2;AF=1;AN=2;AO=3;CIGAR=1X;DP=3;DPB=3;DPRA=0;EPP=9.52472;EPPR=0;GTI=0;LEN=1;MEANALT=1;MQM=60;MQMR=0;NS=1;NUMALT=1;ODDS=8.76405;PAIRED=0;PAIREDR=0;PAO=0;PQA=0;PQR=0;PRO=0;QA=111;QR=0;RO=0;RPP=9.52472;RPPR=0;RUN=1;SAF=3;SAP=9.52472;SAR=0;SRF=0;SRP=0;SRR=0;TYPE=snp GT:DP:RO:QR:AO:QA:GL    1/1:3:0:0:3:111:-10,-0.90309,0
```

I am trying to use awk to match particular regions to their DP value. This is how I'm trying it:

```
awk '$2 == 33564.. { match(DP=) }' file.txt | head
```

Neither the matching nor the wildcards seem to work.

Ideally this code would output `3` because that is what DP equals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `;` or `tab` as the field delimiter. Doing so you can access the number in `$2` and the `DP=` field in `$14`:

```
awk -F'[;\t]' '$2 ~ /33564../{sub(/DP=/,"",$14);print $14}' file.txt
```

The `sub` function is used to remove `DP=` from `$14` which leaves only the value.

Btw, if you also add `=` to the set of field delimiters the value of `DP` will be in field `21`:

```
awk -F'[;\t=]' '$2 ~ /33564../{print $21}' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like $15 works perfectly instead of $14. Also what is `-F` I'm googling it and can't find it.

Comment: Probably I failed to copy the demo data properly. Changed it back to `14`. About `-F`, check `man awk`! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Having worked with genomic data, I believe that the following will be more robust than the previously posted solution.  The main difference is that the key-value pairs are treated as such, without any assumption about their ordering, etc.  The minor difference is the carat ("^") in the regex:

```
awk -F'\t' '
  $2 ~ /^33564../ {
    n=split($8,a,";");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
      split(a[i],b,"=");
      if (b[1]=="DP") {print $2, b[2]} }}'
```

If this script is to be used more than once, then it would be better to abstract the lookup functionality, e.g. like so:

```
awk -F'\t' '
  function lookup(key, string,  i,n,a,b) {
     n=split(string,a,";");
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
       split(a[i],b,"=");
       if (b[1]==key) {return b[2]}
     }
  }
  $2 ~ /^33564../ {
    val = lookup("DP", $8);
    if (val) {print $2, val;}
  }'
```